# Call a service in WSO2 DSS from WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am trying to send a message to a service A in WSO2 DSS from a service B, which is in WSO2 ESB. I generated a client using JAX-WS and can access A directly 
from Java code, but when I export the same code as an Axis2 service and put it into the ESB, I receive the following error:

```
[2017-03-31 08:30:54,110] ERROR - RPCMessageReceiver     org.wso2.carbon.core.services.echo.Echo.getEchoHttpSoap12Endpoint()Lorg/wso2/carbon/core/services/echo/EchoPortType;
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:395)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:142)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.wso2.carbon.core.services.echo.Echo.getEchoHttpSoap12Endpoint()Lorg/wso2/carbon/core/services/echo/EchoPortType;
at service.ChangeName.echoString(ChangeName.java:27)
at service.ChangeName.changeName(ChangeName.java:34)
... 15 more
[2017-03-31 08:30:54,126] ERROR - ServerWorker Error processing POST request for : /services/ChangeName.ChangeNameHttpSoap12Endpoint
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: org.wso2.carbon.core.services.echo.Echo.getEchoHttpSoap12Endpoint()Lorg/wso2/carbon/core/services/echo/EchoPortType;
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:208)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:395)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:142)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.wso2.carbon.core.services.echo.Echo.getEchoHttpSoap12Endpoint()Lorg/wso2/carbon/core/services/echo/EchoPortType;
at service.ChangeName.echoString(ChangeName.java:27)
at service.ChangeName.changeName(ChangeName.java:34)
... 15 more
```

This is the code that works outside ESB:

```
public static String echoString(java.lang.String in) {
    Echo service = Echo();
    EchoPortType port = service.getEchoHttpSoap12Endpoint(); <-- ERROR HERE
    BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider)port;
    bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,LOCAL_ENDPOINT);
    return port.echoString(in);
}
```

Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "when I export the same code as an Axis2 service and put it into the ESB" ? Since you can invoke your DSS service directly from a synapse proxy, I don´t see the point on doing this (other than testing, of course). Anyway, the error seems to point to a missing class in the client you´ve generated. Where did you install it in the ESB ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use generated client as "jar dependency", you need to put this jar to folder src/main/resources/lib
Or put your jar to "dropins" folder of wso2esb.